# getJSON doesn't retrieve data from Django backend

Tags: python, json, django, get, getjson

I'm trying to do regular table update every 10seconds. 
In this code I'm simply adding additional row to the html template table.
But the problem is in my getJSON or in it's handling in backend, I don't know exactly.

js:

```
    setInterval(function(){my_function() }, 10000); 

function my_function(){
    console.log("Congrats!I'm in my_function!");
  $.getJSON('/content/',
    function(data){
        var getContent = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Congrats!I'm in get function!");
        console.log(data.status);
        if (data.status == 'update succeeded'){
            $.each( data.answer, function(i,item){
                $('#refresh tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+ item +'</td></tr>') 
        });
        };
});
};
```

views.py

```
    def content(request):
         if request.method == "GET":
            response_data['status'] = 'Update succeeded'

         """making response body"""

         return HttpResponse(
                 json.dumps(response_data),
                 content_type="application/json"
             )
```

In browser console I get only first log message "Congrats!I'm in my_function!".
Please, help me to find a reason why I don't get into backend 'if'.

Also I have another main 'index' function in my backend with another request (POST). May be it makes some sense and my GET function does not even call?

Comment: You should be able to check that a request has been made to `/content/` in your browser's dev tools. If you show your urls.py, we can check that it's correctly hooked up to your `content` view.

Comment: Try browsing to `/content/` directly to see what django is actually serving.

Comment: My requst has http code 200, everything ik with it.

Comment: What do you mean in browsing to /content/?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my urls, I did't connect views method with GUI request, I had to replace:

```
    url(r'^content/', include('chat.urls') ),
```

with:

```
    url(r'^content/', 'chat.views.content' ),
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem in your view. You must initialize the `response_data` dictionary before using it:

```
def content(request):
     response_data = {}
     if request.method == "GET":
        response_data['status'] = 'Update succeeded'

     """making response body"""

     return HttpResponse(
             json.dumps(response_data),
             content_type="application/json"
         )
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it and nothing changed